# Europe-West2 VPS have US IP

Tags: google-compute-engine, static-ip-address

I am using Google Compute Engine and setup instance in the Europe-West2 region but I just noticed that the IP my machine gets is of US and it has lead to some issues.

I really need to have a static IP of UK for my VPS, I saw the walkthrough on how to assign static IP but I didn't see any article that explains how to get a UK IP in the first place, I tried starting/stopping instance multiple times and all the IP's I got were of US.

Comment: What is the actual issues that you are facing? As I mention in my answer, there isn't really such a thing as a "UK IP", but there may be a solution to the actual underlying problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses themselves don't have a country, they belong to networks (technically autonomous systems) which can span multiple countries, in this case Google's. An IP address can be used for a machine in one particular country, but it's not an intrinsic property of an IP address.

Rather some services try and guess from a combination of sources where an IP address can be allocated. When you say this IP address is in the US, what you really mean is some services has guessed that the IP address is in the US, likely because Google is a US company. The IP geolocation service's incorrect guess is the issue you are facing.

There is no way for you to get a "UK IP" as there is no such thing. The best you can hope for is for your geolocation service to make a better guess, or get an IP address that it guesses better for.

Answer (score 0):

To build on what David said, Google buys IP Address ranges as needed, and registers most of them to their headquarters in Mountain View, CA, and IPs are assigned to VMs from these ranges.

It's also worth mentioning that assigning a static IP to a VM will basically only reserve your current IP or give you an IP similar to what you already have, and cannot be used to configure your own IP, as external facing (public) IP addresses need to be registered, verified and unique.